# How to put ID inside fnSelect()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an anchor to catch code inside a pre tag.
My HTML structure is this:

```
<a href="javascript:fnSelect('id123');>[Select Code]</a>
<pre class="CodeBlock linenums" id="id123"><!-- code --> </pre>
```

For adding the id's to the pre tag and the anchor, I use this code:

```
$('pre').each(function(){
    var id;
    if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined){
      id = 'id'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999) + 1);
      $(this).attr('id',id);
      $(this).prev('a').attr('id',id);
    }
});
```

This creates the same id for the pre tag and the anchor. But the problem is, it generates this HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:fnSelect('id');" id="id38554807">[Select Code]</a>
<pre class="CodeBlock linenums" id="id38554807">
```

And it should be this:

```
<a href="javascript:fnSelect('id38554807');>[Select Code]</a>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't give the anchor an ID at all. Give it a data attribute with the ID that matches the pre and set an event handler on the anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are just setting the id, not updating the href attribute

```
$('pre').each(function(){
        var id;
        if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined){
          id = 'id'+Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999) + 1);
          $(this).attr('id',id);
          $(this).prev('a').attr('href',"javascript:fnSelect('" + id + "')");
        }
     });
```

Or better yet pass your fnSelect method the pre element itself:

```
$('pre').each(function() {
  $(this).prev('a').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    fnSelect(this);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this the jQuery way. Don't give the anchors an ID since they don't need them. They just need a data attribute to hold the of of the corresponding pre tag. Then set an event handler on the anchor's click event:

```js
$('pre').each(function() {
    var id;
    if ($(this).attr('id') == undefined) {
        id = 'id' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999) + 1);
        $(this).attr('id', id);
        $(this).prev('a').attr('data-id', id);
    }
});

$('a[data-id]').click(function() {
    alert($(this).next().attr('id'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">[Select Code]</a>
<pre class="CodeBlock linenums"></pre>

<a href="#">[Select Code]</a>
<pre class="CodeBlock linenums"></pre>

<a href="#">[Select Code]</a>
<pre class="CodeBlock linenums"></pre>

<a href="#">[Select Code]</a>
<pre class="CodeBlock linenums"></pre>
```